# How to prevent users from changing important data in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, websocket

I have a chat application created in laravel and websockets, I am using Laravel echo to listen to the chat channel.

this is an ajax call to send message:

```
  var data = {
     "_token": '{{csrf_token()}}',
     "from_user": '{{ Auth::user()->id }}',
     "chat_id": chat_id,
     "to_user": to_user,
     "message": message
  };

   $.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   data: data,
   url: $url,
   }).done(function( msg ) {
      console.log(msg);
   });
```

even though, I am verifying to see if the sender id matches the currently logged in user's id on the server side, users can easily change the "to_user" id. This can result in unwanted behavior such as the user being able to send a message to someone they don't have access to or in their friend list.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: To prevent that, you can test the `to_user` against a list in the back-end (e.g. friend list) that contains the users they are allowed to chat with. If the `to_user` matches up, forward the message, otherwise discard it.

Comment: Maybe create a session for the two, and validate if a session is available for these two on every sent message. A session can be seomething like just a row on the DB indicating these two are having a conversation right now.

Answer (score 0):

If the id for `to_user` is generated with php, you can generate a key with
`$key=pasword_hash("secret$id", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` and pass this alonmg with $id to the web-client. With **AJAX** send the `$id` along with the `$key` and check in the backend with
`password_verify("secret$id", $key)` , if this fails somebody has changed either $id or $key.

I do this with all data that have to be returned 'as send' to the backend.